# command not executing when called from a case statement in bash

Tags: bash, shell, variables

I'm stuck and trying to troubleshoot why the command within the `case` statement will not execute within this bash script.

If I copy and paste the command into the command line and hardcode the value it will work.
Example:
`psql -h mycluster-1.us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com -U masteruser -d dev -p 5439 -v v1="foo_bar" -f getTableDetails.sql`

In the script, I encased the command within parentheses for possible whitespace issues:

```
    #!/usr/local/bin/bash

    set -e
    set -x


    cluster_to_endpoint() {
      case "$1" in
        c01)
          RUNCMD=$(psql -h mycluster-1.us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com -U masteruser -d dev -p 5439 -v v1="$NAME" -f getTableDetails.sql)
          ;;
        c02)
          RUNCMD=$(psql -h mycluster-2.us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com -U masteruser -d dev -p 5439 -v v1="$NAME" -f getTableDetails.sql)
          ;;
      esac
    }


    while getopts ":c:n:" opt; do
      case $opt in
        c) cluster="$OPTARG";;
        n) name="$OPTARG";;
        *) usage
           exit 1
           ;;
      esac
    done
```

I am executing the script like so: `./myscript.sh -c c01 -n foo_bar`

I've also tried just removing the `()` as well:

```
c01) 
   psql -h mycluster-2.us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com -U masteruser -d dev -p 5439 -v v1="$NAME" -f getTableDetails.sql;;
```

It looks like the variables are set.

```
$ ./myscript.sh -c c01 -n foo_bar
+ getopts :c:n: opt
+ case $opt in
+ cluster=c01
+ getopts :c:n: opt
+ case $opt in
+ name=foo_bar
+ getopts :c:n: opt
```

So why isn't the command executing? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command that isn't executing is inside a function, `cluster_to_endpoint`, that's never called.

Comment: Yes, forgot to add that at the end. That did it. Thanks!